# Passing Access modfiers to a method in PHP Returns a Parse error

Tags: php, iterator

I have been trying to pass various access modifiers (public, private, and protected) in my method (3rd line). Unfortunately, I get a Parse error when running the code. Please, see the code below:

```
class MappedIteratorDemo implements Iterator
{
    public function __construct(private array $items = []){}

    public function current()
    {
        // TODO: Implement current() method.
        return current($this->items);
    }

    public function next()
    {
        // TODO: Implement next() method.
        return next($this->items);
    }

    public function key()
    {
        // TODO: Implement key() method.
        return key($this->items);
    }

    public function valid()
    {
        // TODO: Implement valid() method.
        return key($this->items) !== null;
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        // TODO: Implement rewind() method.
        return reset($this->items);
    }
}

$mappedArray = [
    'name'      => 'Ola',
    'location'  => 'Essen, Germany',
    'role'      => 'Software Developer',
];

$mappedIterDemo = new MappedIteratorDemo($mappedArray);
foreach ($mappedIterDemo as $item =>$value)
{
    print "$item : $value" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

And its corresponding error

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'private' (T_PRIVATE), expecting variable (T_
VARIABLE) in ...
```

My PHP version is PHP: 8.0, IDE: PHP Storm

Suggestions/Advice would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Your code works 100% for me in PHP 8, both in PhpStorm as well as [online](https://3v4l.org/shfW3#v8.0.11). I would remove the `return` from `next()`, however, since it is supposed to be ignored per for the docs.

Comment: WFM https://3v4l.org/shfW3 Looks like you're not _actually_ running PHP8 in this context.

Comment: Thanks @chrisHaas I have been able to figure it out.

Comment: @sammitch, thanks for the URL. I have bookmarked it and it´ll be very useful for my development going forward.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to you guys for the comment.

So, I initially thought changing the PHP version at the bottom of the IDE would do the magic not knowing that I also have to change the Interpreter version under preferences/settings.

I realized that my PHP CLI interpreter was in version **7.4.23.** I updated it to version **8.0** and it works really well.

This could also help people who could struggle with the same challenges in the future.